# JAVAFX: difference between setMaxWidth() and maxWidthProperty().set()

Tags: java, javafx, properties, width, javafx-2

I have a textfield `tfCivico` which I want change width, so I try with

```
 tfCivico.setMaxWidth(60);
```

with no results, but if I try

```
 tfCivico.maxWidthProperty().set(60);
```

it works..why this? isn't the same thing?

Comment: What is the type of `tfCivico`?

Comment: textfield type of javafx

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference.

`setMaxWidth` makes a call to `maxWidth.set(...)`:

```
public final void setMaxWidth(double value) {
    if (maxWidth == null) {
        _maxWidth = value;
        requestParentLayout();
    } else {
        maxWidth.set(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer is correct: these are identical. If you want to claim otherwise, edit your question with a [MCVE] that demonstrates the different behaviors.